# Android Studio builds count

Tags: android, build, count

is it possible to see how many builds a Project has since start on the Computer.

Mabye 10 or 100 or 1000?

Manually or in android code?

Is there anything that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here we are - some back to you

Code looks now like this

```
 // Setting Preferences
    def f_name = 'Buildxx.txt'
    def f_path = 'e:/'
    def Seperator =';'
    def BFile = new File(f_path+f_name);
    def LineList = []
    def readln = javax.swing.JOptionPane.&showInputDialog
    def usertext = readln 'What have you done?'


    def DateTime = new Date();
    def sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd/MM/YYYY kk:mm:ss")
    def x =0;
          if (BFile.exists()){
               def Max = BFile.length();
              BFile.eachLine { line ->
                  x++;
                  LineList.add(line);

              }
            def LastLine = LineList.last();

              def number = ""
              number = LastLine.split(' ');
              def InumStr = number[0];
              def Inum = InumStr.toInteger();

              def Nextnumber = Inum+1;
                  BFile.append(System.getProperty("line.separator")+Nextnumber+" "  + sdf.format(DateTime)+ " "+usertext)
    }
    else
          {
              BFile.write("0 "+ sdf.format(DateTime)+ " Start of the project");
         }
```

at the end you have a log-file which you can open in Excel (csv.file) ...
and it looks after a couple of formatting like this 
(i love coloured Excel Sheets ;) )

[image]

> Notice: Synchronizing the Gradle files is also counted.

That's the only thing that troubles :(
Maybe there is some property to read

Answer (score 0):

Never thought about adding a counter to Gradle. But here you go. Add this to `build.gradle`:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xy"
    // ...

    def buildCountFile = new File("D:\\gradle-counter.txt")
    String content = ""
    if(buildCountFile.exists()) {
        content = buildCountFile.getText('UTF-8')
    }
    int count = 0;
    if(content.isNumber()) {
        count = content.toInteger() + 1;
    }
    buildCountFile.write(count.toString())
}
```

To create a daily counter you can add something like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xy"
    // ...

    def buildCountFile = new File("D:\\gradle-counter.txt")
    def sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
    String date = sdf.format(new Date())
    String content = ""
    if(buildCountFile.exists()) {
        content = buildCountFile.getText('UTF-8')
    }
    String dateRegex = "(" + date.replace("/","\\/") + ":\\s*)(\\d+)"
    def matcher = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(dateRegex).matcher(content)
    if (matcher.find()) {
        // Current date already in the file
        int countToday = matcher.group(2).toInteger()
        countToday = countToday + 1
        String newLine = matcher.group(1) + countToday
        content = content.replace(matcher.group(), newLine)
    } else {
        // Need to create a new line with current date
        content = content + date + ": 1\r\n";
    }
    buildCountFile.write(content)
}
```

Content of `D:\gradle-counter.txt`:

```
01/21/2015: 4
02/21/2015: 2
```

Notice: 
Synchronizing the Gradle files is also counted.

Source code is for Windows, needs small changes to work with Linux.

Comment: Great if it works - but where have I put the code in? Is it possible to put add date/time?

Comment: This has to be put into `build.gradle`. I have added a daily counter to my answer.

Comment: Are there any Dialog boxes where I can put some text in to the file?

Comment: When you open Android Studio, the files are in that box on the left. Below your Java files, there is a category called `Gradle Scripts`. If you expand that category, there are two `build.gradle` files. Choose the one that says `Module: xy`. Add the code from my answer into the block `defaultConfig`.

Comment: No I mean to add some text to the file with every build :)

Comment: So you don't want to count, just add text?

Comment: I would like to add to every build a couple of words and count

Comment: The syntax is quite similar to Java. You should try to program it on your own. Anyway, this is the code for adding some text to a file using Gradle: `def buildCountFile = new File("D:\\gradle-text.txt"); String content = ""; if(buildCountFile.exists()) {; content = buildCountFile.getText('UTF-8'); } content = content + "xy\r\n"; buildCountFile.write(content)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my way - this is my Version ... without user input anyway - I have started something with console or swing but until now it doesn't work -
but I try it again

```
// Setting Preferences
def f_name = 'Buildlog.txt'
def f_path = 'e:/'
def BFile = new File(f_path+f_name);

def DateTime = new Date();
def sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd/MM/YYYY k:m:s")
if (BFile.exists()){
    BFile.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + sdf.format(DateTime))
 } else {
 }
```

Comment: This answer must have been updated instead of posting a new one (on this same question) which is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28701666).